# Using DeMorgan’s rule, state the negation of the statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Using DeMorgan’s rule, state the negation of the statement: “The car is out of gas
or the fuel line is plugged.”

Let C stand for “The car is out of gas” and let F stand for “the fuel line is plugged”. then the answer is $(\lnot C\lor \lnot F) \equiv \lnot C\land \lnot F.$

Comment: Excuse me ... but it is the third question regarding De Morgan's law in about an hour; you received hints, answers and link to Wiki's source for explanation about it. I think it is useful for you to spend some time re-reading them.

Comment: Be careful how you write the left-hand side of your answer. There is a big difference between $(\lnot C) \vee (\lnot F)$ and $\lnot(C \vee F)$.  One of these is equivalent to $\lnot C \wedge \lnot F$; the other is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using DeMorgan’s rule, state the negation of the statement: “The car *is* out of gas *or* the fuel line *is* plugged.”

This statement is a disjunction; that is an 'or'-joined statement. Conjunctions are the 'and'-joined statement.

DeMorgan states: `The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of negations.`

The negation is thus: "The car *is not* out of gas *and* the fuel line *is not* plugged."

Answer (score 1):

Start with the original statement, which according to your key, is:$$C\lor F$$

Now negate this, and then apply DeMorgan's:

$$\lnot(C\lor F) \equiv \lnot C \land \lnot F$$

So the negation of the given sentence translates to:

> "The car **is not** out of gas, **and** the fuel line **is not** plugged."

Try to understand the logic behind DeMorgan's and what the negation of a disjunction means